# How to get the value of an elsewhere defined variable in a PHP's fpm.conf?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sh

I'm in the situation where I need to verify on a NOT self-hosted linux-server that the provider actually increased the max_children of php-fpm.

```
pm.max_children = ${FPM_MAX_CHILDREN}
```

I thought that I can echo the variable in the terminal and receive its value but it does not work.

The 'ps aux' command is not available to me on the server and I've searched (grep) the half server for the definition of the variable without success.

Does anyone here have an idea how I can check the value instead? I really appreciate your help. Kind regards.

Comment: What do you mean by _defined elsewhere_? Where/how is the variable defined?

Comment: I mean it like "black-box-kind-of-elsewhere" ;)

Comment: This is too fuzzy. If you don't specify, how exactly a variable is defined, and how that definition is found in your program, the question does not make sense. From your question, I don't even see whether the "variable" is meant to be a PHP variable, or a shell variable, or an environment variable.

Answer (score -1):

If your provider allows you to use the php CLI you just need to use `php -i | grep "pm.max_children"`

Another method would be to create a php file in your document root with this content:

```
<?php

phpinfo( );

?>
```

Then access that file with your browser and search for the parameter you need.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Helped me collect enough information to be sure that the provider restricts it completely.

You can also run   php -r 'phpinfo();'   inside a terminal to output the information directly - no need for a php file. But sadly it is not displaying the max_children.

Comment: `phpinfo();` is NOT displaying the `max_children` value.